# cannot install grails 2.4.4 local plugin( zip file)

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

how to install any plugin locally in an grails project if we have zip file of that plugin without configuring that plugin  in BuildConfig.groovy file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install locally for grails version 2.4.

For lower version put jar in lib folder and mention in BuildConfig.groovy (necessary)